# Where can I find a room for day use in Manila, Philippines?

Tags: layovers, hotels, accommodation, philippines, manila

One of the flights I am considering taking next month has a rather long layover in Manila Airport (MNL) during the day: it arrives early in the morning and leaves in the evening. I may want to sleep and walk around the city a bit, so I'd like a place to stay in Manila for around 10 hours and I've like to stay outside the airport. Also, I don't want to have to pay the price for two nights. Where can I find a room for day use in Manila, Philippines?

Comment: None of  the typical  sites that I use serves Manila, so this may be tricky. On the other hand, hotel rooms near MNL are quite inexpensive: why don't you just get a cheap room for 2 nights ? This will still be a lot cheaper than a day room in the US :-)

Comment: @Hilmar thanks for looking at it, yes agreed, 2 nights is the backup plan. Definitely still way cheaper than in the US indeed!

Comment: To help us recommend a nearby hotel, please share which terminal would you be arriving in Manila?

Answer (score 4):

When I had a long layover in Manila last year I actually used [Klook](https://www.klook.com/en-US/hotels) to book a day room near the airport. I found them really convenient since I could pick the hotel and time that worked best. There were a bunch of options available for around 6 hours which was perfect for me.

Comment: Thanks, how does one list rooms available for day use on Klook? I couldn't find the option yet.

Comment: On Klook, you just need to select the number of guests and enter your arrival/departure times in the dates section to see the day use room options.

Answer (score 2):

Hotel SOGO is everywhere in the Philippines. I think they're accepting stays as short as 3 hours but I usually stay there 12 hours and ask the hotel to call a taxi upon checkout. There are certainly many hotels that are better and newer than SOGO